# Stop su from asking for a password

Tags: sudo, su

I am trying to run the following command as `deploy` from Java (the JVM is running as the user `tomcat`):

```
sudo -u deploy /path/to/my/bash/script.sh PARAM1 PARAM2
```

My sudoers file has the following in it:

```
tomcat ALL=(deploy) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/bash/script.sh *
```

But I get `sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` in my Java application. Therefore, I changed my invocation to be:

```
su --session-command="/path/to/my/bash/script.sh PARAM1 PARAM2" deploy
```

But now I get `standard in must be a tty` in Java.

I have checked, and by doing the following I can see that `sudo` doesn't prompt for a password but `su` does.

```
[root@mybox bin]# sudo su tomcat
[tomcat@mybox bin]$ sudo -u deploy /path/to/my/bash/script.sh PARAM1 PARAM2
output of script with PARAM1 PARAM2
[tomcat@mybox bin]$ su --session-command="/path/to/my/bash/script.sh PARAM1 PARAM2" deploy
Password:
su: incorrect password
```

Obviously `sudoers` is only for `sudo` (hence the name). Is there another way of running the command as `deploy` without a password prompt?

I am developing this on centos 6.3 but it will eventually be running on RHEL5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can relax the `requiretty` setting in the `/etc/sudoer`.

*excerpt from sudoers man page*

```
requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real 
                tty. When this flag is set, sudo can only be run from a login
                session and not via other means such as cron(8) or cgi-bin 
                scripts.  This flag is off by default.
```

By default this line says everyone must have tty access when using `sudo`:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

You can relax it per user and/or group like this:

```
$ sudo visudo
# group
Defaults:%group !requiretty
# user
Defaults:user   !requiretty
```

**note:** The `!` means `not`.

See the [sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) & [sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) man pages for more details.